# ElasticSearch: Creating a bool query with OR AND clauses

Tags: sql, elasticsearch, where-clause

I am trying to convert a sql query to its equivalent elasticsearch query ( the sql tabel and ES index are similar). Its a combination of AND/OR.

I have a SQL query such that

```
SELECT DISTINCT N_ID 
FROM   MYTABLE 
WHERE  ( [C_ID] = 4 AND E_ID = 765) 
         OR ( C_ID = 6 AND E_ID = 642 ))
```

This is my equivalent Elastic query

```
GET  mytable_index/_search
{
    "query": {
        "bool": {
            "should": [{
                    "must": [{
                            "term": {
                                "C_ID": 4
                            }
                        }, {
                            "term": {
                                "E_ID": 765
                            }
                        }
                    ]
                }, {
                    "must": [{
                            "term": {
                                "C_ID": 6
                            }
                        }, {
                            "term": {
                                "E_ID": 642
                            }
                        }
                    ]
                }
            ]
        }
    }
}
```

But i get the following exception:

```
 {
            "type": "parsing_exception",
            "reason": "[must] query malformed, no start_object after query name",
            "line": 5,
            "col": 14
  }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
This problem will not simply  solve using query. For achiving the distinct values you  need aggregations.

Please refer to my query

{
    "query": {
        "bool": {
            "should": [{
                    "bool": {
                        "must": [{
                                "match": {
                                    "C_ID": 4
                                }
                            }, {
                                "match": {
                                    "I_ID": 765
                                }
                            }
                        ]
                    }
                }, {
                    "bool": {
                        "must": [{
                                "match": {
                                    "C_ID": 6
                                }
                            }, {
                                "match": {
                                    "I_ID": 642
                                }
                            }
                        ]
                    }
                }
            ]
        }
    },
    "size":0,
    "aggs": {
    "distinct_values": {
      "terms": {
        "field": "N_ID",
        "size": 1000
      }
    }
  }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

I was missing another bool clause inside of the should

```
GET  mytable_index/_search
{
    "query": {
        "bool": {
            "should": [{
                    "bool": {
                        "must": [{
                                "match": {
                                    "C_ID": 4
                                }
                            }, {
                                "match": {
                                    "I_ID": 765
                                }
                            }
                        ]
                    }
                }, {
                    "bool": {
                        "must": [{
                                "match": {
                                    "C_ID": 6
                                }
                            }, {
                                "match": {
                                    "I_ID": 642
                                }
                            }
                        ]
                    }
                }
            ]
        }
    }
}
```